# Tor Telnet control gives Authentication Required error on any command

Tags: telnet, tor, privacy

I am trying to connect to a running instance of Tor with the Tor Control (TC) Protocol using Telnet on the ControlPort (specified in the **torrc** file) on Windows.

Whenever I connect using Windows's own implementation of Telnet or with PuTTY, I just receive an empty prompt.  Knowing that TC only allows the `AUTHENTICATE "[pass]"`, `PROTOCOLINFO`, or `QUIT` commands, I enter one of those.  No matter which command I enter, I receive the error `514 Authentication Required`.

So, Tor is not letting me authenticate and thus I cannot control Tor with Telnet commands.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, in PuTTY at least, I have to specify a **Raw** connection instead of a **Telnet** connection. But, using `telnet localhost 9051` in the Windows prompt now gives me a `250 OK` on `authenticate "[pass]"`, though it doesn't print the `authenticate` command as I type it.

Comment: telnet doesn't print what you type by default, you have to tell it to.

Comment: As i said in my answer you did not see anything when you type it. Then if the pass is correct you'll see a OK statement....From my answer : Type: authenticate "" (also if you did not see anything) and you'll see 250 OK.

Answer (score 2):

- First you must set the ControlPort in your `torrc` file like this:

  ```
  ControlPort 9051
  ```
- Then restart Tor or Vidalia and set the authentification to *None* in *Preferences → Advanced*
- Then from the command line in Windows type:

  ```
  telnet localhost 9051
  ```

  (it seems nothing happens and the screen remains black)
- Type: `authenticate ""` (also if you did not see anything) and you'll see `250 OK`.

Now you can send tor commands like signal newnym.